# How can I hide table column when all "td" in the column are empty?

Tags: jquery, html

My Table Looks likes this:

```
  <table id="mytable" width="500" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to hide respective column if all `td`  of that column are empty else that column should be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to loop over each `th`, use its index to reference the `tds` in the same column, check if they're all empty, and if they are, hide all `th` and `td` elements in that column.

```
/* loop over each th */
$('th').each(function(idx, el) {

    /* check every td in the same column, see if they contain any text */
    var check = !! $('tr').find('td:eq(' + idx + ')').filter(function() {
       return $.trim( $(this).text() ).length; 
    }).length;

    /* toggle the display of each th and td in this column, based on the check above */
    $('tr').find('td:eq(' + idx + '), th:eq(' + idx + ')').toggle( check );


});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pLyshg7/)

Comment: Answer is correct but how to pass table id and do the same

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
$("#mytable td:empty" ).hide();
$("#mytable td:not(:empty)").show();
```

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$("#mytable tbody tr").each(function (index, element) {
    if ($(element).find("td").not(':empty').length == 0) {
        $(element).hide();
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L9q8j3z/)

Remove 4 from 4th row and run

Comment: Your solution works but I want to hide columns not rows

Answer (score 0):

If your column has specific data like `'-'` try this one:

```
    $('th').each(function(idx, el) {
    var check = !! $('tr').find('td:eq(' + idx + ')').filter(function() {

           //If your column has specific data like `'-'` try this one:
           return $(this).text() != '-'; 


        }).length;
        $('tr').find('td:eq(' + idx + '), th:eq(' + idx + ')').toggle( check );
    });
```